# div inside wrapper div not aligning bottom

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, margins

I´m having trouble getting this solved, though it must be pretty simple thing...

I have a div wrapper containing other div elements on my page. All are aligned using `margin-top` in `px`; but the last one (footer) I need it to be `margin-bottom:0px`, so that it shows at the bottom of the wrapper, but  that´s not working: the footer shows always on top of the page.

I went to other align issues here, tried giving `position: absolute` to the footer and `position:relative` to the wrapper; didn´t work. I tried using % heights and min-height also...but still the footer on top

I´m getting a bit frustrated with this :(

**CSS :**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-image: url(images/modulo-pattern-grey-light.gif);
}
#body-quienes {
    height: 800px;
}
#pagina {
    height: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff url(images/footer.gif) left bottom no-repeat;
    width: 980px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #999;
}

.header {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0 px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: 70px;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-image: url(images/header.gif);
}

.menu_container{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    margin-top: 220px;  
}
.main_menu ul { 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin:0px;
    list-style-type: none;  
}
.main_menu ul li {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:11px; 
    letter-spacing:4px;
    text-align:right; 
    line-height:35px;  
    list-style-type:none;
}
.main_menu ul li a  {
    padding-right: 25px;  
    text-decoration:none;  
    color:#999;
    display: inline-block;  
} 
.main_menu ul li a.selected {
    color: #bc4c9b;
    font-weight:bold; 
    background: url(images/circle.gif) right center no-repeat;
}   
.main_menu ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;  
    color:#999;  
    font-weight:bold;  
    background:url(images/circle_grey.gif) right center no-repeat;
}  

.quienes_pic{
    position: absolute;
    height: 259px;
    width: 174px;
    margin-left: 306px;
    margin-top: 230px;
    background-image: url(images/san.jpg);
}
.quienes_text{
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 25px;
    border-left: 2px dotted #ccc;
    width: 395px;
    height: 360px;
    margin-left: 510px;
    margin-top: 230px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:12px;
    color: #bc4c9b;
    line-height:20px;
    content-left-padding: 25px; 
}
.footer {
    position:absolute;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 490px;
    width: 460px;
    height: 98px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    background-color: #bc4c9b;
 }
```

**HTML :**

```
<body id="body-quienes">
    <div id="pagina">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="flashanim"></div>
        <div class="menu_container">
            <div class="main_menu">  
                <ul>  
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  
                    <li><a class="selected" >Quiénes Somos</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="consultoria.html">Consultoría</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="capacitacion.html">Capacitación</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="academico.html">Académico / Artículos</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="alianzas.html">Alianzas</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="proyectos.html">Proyectos</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>   
                </ul>  
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="quienes_pic"></div>
        <div class="quienes_text">Main Text</div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>​
```

Comment: You may need to go back to basics of css. Why area most of your divs absolutely positioned in the first place ?

Comment: You are not making your point clear: first you say "it appears always at the bottom of the wraper", then "the footer shows always on top of the page". You need to make your question very clear and remove unneeded sentences .

Comment: I AM at the basics of CSS :) I read a tutorial that used this kind of positioning for divs, may be it was not a good one...I´ll try to find better info.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry English is not my mother tongue, I hope now it´s clear what the problem is: footer shows on top, though is given margin-bottom: 0px

Answer (score 0):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxLSH/).  It still doesn't appear correctly in my mind, but I think that's because I'm not quite sure of the design you are going for but what I did in the fiddle puts your pink footer at the bottom of the page.

What I did was I took the footer out of the `pagina` `<div>` and set it below it and voila, your footer is at the bottom of the page.  Let me know if this works for you or if you need something different.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the demo and kindness :) What I need is the footer to be at the bottom of the `.pagina` wraper. Like in this page: http://www.casadelviento.com.ar/

Comment: Oh ok, so the menu is part of the footer then?  If so, you should update your question with more specifics of what the footer contains.  Looking at the code as you have it, you have nothing within the footer.

Comment: Sorry @eliana but I've been playing with this in a fiddle, and I can get the pink to show at the bottom, even within the `pagina` but I am still unsure of exactly what you are trying to achieve with the code you provide.  If you can be more specific, or offer a little more code that could help us understand, I would be willing to take another look at it and see what I can do but without further clarification I feel at a loss

Comment: [here is what I have now](http://http://jsfiddle.net/W2HsP/), with the footer back into `pagina`, removed the `position: absolute`'s, cleaned up some bad margin coding (you had margins set on a class, but at the bottom of that same css you had margin:0) and did what I could but again, I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks, I couldn´t link to the code, seems the link is not working (?) No, I don´t want to have the menu at the bottom, it was just an example of footer placement that fits the design I´m working with.

Comment: Sorry, try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Akcnq/).  It actually just looks a lot like the other one but with the footer in the `#pagina`.  To be honest, I think you need to start your CSS for this from scratch.  I think what's hurting you (besides the absolute positioning) is a lot of your widths and margins/paddings.  If I could see a live demo of you page (other than fiddle) I could inspect the elements in the browser which will give me a much clearer picture of what's going on. Plus it will be easier to edit and check.  Do you have a live demo I could look at?

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, you all are right, seems `position:absolute` is causing the problem. I removed it from my code, and the layout is quite a mess, but the footer is now `margin-bottom=0` as it should. Since I was in a hurry (and needed the paddings and correct aligments for the rest of the divs), I ended up using the Sticky Footer code: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/, which finally worked fine for me.

Comment: and yes I do have a demo, an image is worth a thousand words :) http://www.sandracabrera.com.ar/desarrollo/sandra-cabrera-cv.html

Answer (score 0):

As someone has already asked, why are the majority of your div absolutely positioned. Read up about the different types of positioning, what they do and when you should use them.

Seeing as your footer is absolutely positioned, I would assume you need to add the following code to the footer section in your css.

```
bottom: 0px;
```

Give this a try.

But a word of advice, Dont use absolute positioning and margin-left to align your divs to the center. For that all you need to do it use:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I´ll do so. Bottom: 0px is not working, neither is margin-bottom:0px. I´m not trying to center the divs, just to position them at a specific distance of eachother.

Comment: might be an idea to not use relative positioning or no positioning at all then use margin-top: px;
or use clear: both;

Comment: I removed all positioning code and left just the margin-top and margin-left to position the elements; but all the layout is messed up. I´ll read more on the subject, thanks.

Comment: And yes, you are right, absolute positioning is the problem...I just have to figure out how to achieve the same result without it :)